# How to get pusher instance in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I want to know how we can get Pusher instance or Pusher Facade in our Laravel app.
After install pusher SDK in Laravel. I need to get that object for authenticating users in pusher for private channels.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, please close your question.

Comment: What was the answer?

Answer (score 3):

`Broadcast::driver('pusher')->getPusher()`